# How to store and handle ingame recipes

Tags: c#, xna

I am building a Terraria like game and I am having a problem with where to store the recipes..

basically what my game should do is go through the player inventory (which is an array of id's) and check recipe by recipe if all the item's are in the player inventory.

I dont know how to store the recipes and how to handle them, i though of using array but the size of the array vary from item to item, I though of list too but it is a lot of writing and I want a "clean" code.

what should i use to store my recipes?

and if you suggest me to use array, should i make it static and declare every recipe and my "Crafting" class?

thanks.

**(The recipe's should be id's and the amount per id)**

Comment: What about using a `List<T>`?

Comment: This basically comes down to list comparisons, if you're doing this the Terraria way. That's very simple in C# (though far simpler in F# or Nemerle). LINQ will probably help a lot.

Comment: In the world of collections in .NET you have a lot of choices: from the humble array to sorted dictionaries and so on. You can even use a list of keyvaluepairs if you have identical keys. The list is long and the choice is yours! :)

Comment: I'm interested to hear if my answer was beneficial, were you able to get your feature working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never played Terraria, but it sounds like a pretty simple LINQ query:

If your recipe object contains a List of `InventoryItem`:

```
struct InventoryItem
{
   int itemId;
   int itemCount;
}

class Recipe
{
   String name;
   List<InventoryItem> RequiredItems { get; set; }
}
```

And your inventory is a list of the same structure, then its just:

```
bool canUseRecipe = recipe.RequiredItems.All(i => 
   {
      InventoryItem itemInInventory = Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.itemId == i.itemId);
      return itemInInventory == null ? false : itemInInventory.itemCount >= i.itemCount;
   });
```

There might be a way to collapse that into a one liner, but this is probably more clear!

You could also seperate it out into a different function:

```
bool canUseRecipe = recipe.RequiredItems.All(i => SufficientItemsInInventory(i));
//Or
bool canUseRecipe = recipe.RequiredItems.All(SufficientItemsInInventory);
...

private bool SufficentItemsInInventory(InventoryItem item)
{
   InventoryItem itemInInventory = Inventory.FirstOrDefault(i => i.itemId == item.itemId);
   return itemInInventory == null ? false : itemInInventory.itemCount >= i.itemCount;
});
```

Comment: Rather than a one liner in this case, I'd make the larger lambda into a method. Then you get an extra name for more clarity. It's complex enough to be a method, after all.

Comment: @Magus, agreed. Added this alternative to my answer. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can simplify it down even more now, because it is already a function of `InventoryItem`: `.All(SufficientItemsInInventory)`. An alternative name could be `ItemsAreInInventory` so it flows better after the `All`. This also removes the redundant lambda. It may not be more clear to people at first, but this is a technique worth learning, because it abstracts more details away.

Comment: @Magus, I generally don't use that notation (for the exact reason that its not as obvious whats going on), but it is definitely a good thing to know about! Added as an alternative way to run the "All" query.