# Linq with regular array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of *Item* (A class I've made), and this is what I try to do:

```
foreach (Recipe recipe in recipes)
{
    if (recipe.All(i =>
    {
        Item item = inventory.Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == i.ID);
        return (item == null) ? false : (item.Amount >= i.Amount);
    }))
        ableToCraft.Add(recipe);
}
```

thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434025/how-to-store-and-handle-ingame-recipes) question.

The problem is, where I run through the inventory with *x* (***x => x.ID == i.ID***), I come across *x* begin null because the cell the x try to point to from the array is null as well.

How can I fix that problem and make the program skip when they come across a null cell in the array?/

Comment: `x != null && x.ID == i.ID`?

Comment: That work's thanks, I added Where function right before the FirstOrDefault and it worked as well but I rather use your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for *null* first:

```
inventory.Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && x.ID == i.ID);
```

Or filter the records before `FirstOrDefault`:

```
inventory.Inventory
.Where(x => x != null)
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == i.ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
(Recipe recipe in recipes)
                {
                    if (recipe.All(i =>
                    {
                        // this
                        Item item = inventory.Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && x.ID == i.ID);
                        return (item == null) ? false : (item.Amount >= i.Amount);
                    }))
                        ableToCraft.Add(recipe);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundling it all into that `foreach` is a little ... confusing.

For maintenance, I'd use a `Func<bool, Recipe>` to make it easier to maintain.

```
Func<Recipe, bool> pricesAreCorrectForItem = (recipe) =>
     {
          var validInventoryItems = inventory.Inventory.Where(x=>x!=null);
          var item = validInventoryItems.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == recipe.ID);
          return item == null ? false : (item.Amount >= recipe.Amount);
     };

foreach(Recipe recipe in recipes)
{
    if(recipe.All(pricesAreCorrectForItem))
        ableToCraft.Add(recipe);
}
```